# This sentence is interchangeable like this?

Tags: synonyms

'I eat two apples per hour' can be interchanged into 'I eat two apples each'? per=for each, each=for each. I think it is grammatically perfect.

Comment: What does "technically" mean.  This usually mean "according to the strict definitions"  But there are no official definitions in English.  I think you mean "is it correct even though I know it isn't correct"... But that is a weird question to ask.

Comment: It would have to be "I eat two apple**s** per hour", but this is a rather odd sentence, suggesting that you eat an apple every half-hour for at least several hours. "I eat two apple each" makes no sense at all. Do you mean "I eat two apples each hour"?

Comment: @Kate Bunting Yes why can't I use each instead of each hour?

Comment: Because there is no context to understand that "each" means "each hour".  Instead it would mean "each apple".  And "I eat two apples each apple" is nonsense.

Comment: @James K  Then, if there is the context, each can mean each hour?

Comment: I can't think of any way to provide that context, except saying "each hour".

Comment: No. Without a governed noun phrase, _each_ is usually distributive over the topic (normally the subject, unless _each_ is the subject, in which case it would refer to the topic established in previous discourse). You could say _The hours seemed to last a year each!_, and then _each_ would refer to the hours. But it took me a while to think up a plausible example of that with "hours".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you say

> I gave the boys an apple each.

We understand "each" to mean "to each boy"

Similarly we can say

> I eat two apples each hour.

It is a lot of apples, you will get sick, but your grammar would be correct!

But without context we can't understand "each" to mean "each hour".  So

> I eat two apples each.

Is not correct English. It is incorrect grammar and highly non-idiomatic.  You need to say "each hour" or "each day" or even "in each town" or "on each Friday"

You can't leave out important words that provide meaning not supplied by the context.

Comment: What about this expression 'I eat two apples each hour, that is I eat two apples each' then each can mean each hour?

Comment: Ungrammatical I'd still understand "each" to mean "each apple"